# Why am I unable to create an index using low privileged user

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

[image: I'm checking effective permissions for the user i'm logged on with]

I created a Role to which this user belongs to, and have set execute rights on multiple Schemas, however on Data Schema i need to be able to dynamically create and delete tables. Based on the screenshot, i gave all available permissions to the role (and user effectively) but when i try creating an index this is the error i get :

> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors

There are no previous errors :(

This is the code that should create the table and indexes :

```
CREATE TABLE [Data].[24C6B124-137C-4F06-B690-F80C0C0A1347]
(
    [ApplicationId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [UUID] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_24C6B124-137C-4F06-B690-F80C0C0A1347] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ApplicationId] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];

ALTER TABLE [Data].[24C6B124-137C-4F06-B690-F80C0C0A1347] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_24C6B124-137C-4F06-B690-F80C0C0A1347_UUID]  
        DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR [UUID];

ALTER TABLE [Data].[24C6B124-137C-4F06-B690-F80C0C0A1347] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_24C6B124-137C-4F06-B690-F80C0C0A1347_Application] 
        FOREIGN KEY([ApplicationId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Application] ([ApplicationId])
                ON DELETE CASCADE;

rolling back...
```

If I execute same query with `sa` level user, it runs with no issues.

My best bet is that this is a permission problem related to some permission required to create indexes, but my search and experiments lead me nowhere.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @Larnu Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: *"See previous errors"* what previous errors? If SQL Server is telling you there are previous errors, there will be some. That, however, doesn't sound like an error from SQL Server.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks, figured it out quickly after i posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i posted a question, i figured it out so let me share :

I needed to add reference permission also on the table [dbo].[Application] that's in dbo Schema unlike table in question that's in Data Schema.